# Understanding bash logic. (Operators and quotes)

Tags: bash, operators, quotes, double-quotes

```
bktitle="Bash"
echo "New book title '$bktitle' added successfully!"
```

I thought single quotes made everything literal? But this was give the output of

> ```
> New Book title Bash added successfully!
> ```

```
egrep ^[0-9]+$
```

Why would this line only accept integers? I know this `^` is for starting with, the + is for means the preceding must occur at least once. But for my knowledge of `$`, I'm not sure. Would it not accept something like `1a`?

```
egrep ^[0-9]+[.][0-9][0-9]
```

Why would this line only accept decimal numbers for exactly 2 decimal places? I thought the `+` would only allow for it to make sure that the starting number must be `0-9`. So why isn't it accepting something like `1a.00`?

Comment: it's not related to bash ..

Comment: is this not the bash language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I thought single quotes made everything literal? But this was give the output of `New Book title 'BASH' added successfully`.

In your example:

```
bktitle="BASH"
echo "New book title '$bktitle' added successfully!"
```

Inside a double-quoted string (`""`), single-quotes (`''`) are not interpreted, but variables are.

If you did this:

```
bktitle="BASH"
echo 'New book title \'$bktitle\' added successfully!'
```

Or this:

```
bktitle="BASH"
echo "New book title \'$bktitle\' added successfully!"
```

Or this:

```
bktitle="BASH"
echo 'New book title $bktitle added successfully!'
```

You would see (in the first two examples):

> `New book title '$bktitle' added successfully!`

Or:

> `New book title $bktitle added successfully!`

Single quotes don't interpret variables or double quotes (or `\escape sequences`).

> Why would this line only accept integers? I know this `^` is for starting with, the `+` is for means the preceding must occur at least once.. but for my knowledge of `$` I'm not sure. but would it not accept something like `1a`?

You're right about `^` and `+`! `[0-9]` matches any number between 0 and 9. `$` means *ends-with*, and represents the end of the string.

```
^[0-9]+$
```

Matches any string containing 1 or more numbers, from beginning to end, and nothing else.

Now for your last question:

> `egrep '^[0-9]+[.][0-9][0-9]'`
>   Why would this line only accept decimal numbers for exactly 2 decimal places? i thought the `+` would only allow for it to make sure that the starting number must be 0-9. so why isn't it accepting something like `1a.00`?

Yes, this would match decimal numbers containing exactly two decimal places.

If you wanted it to accept letters as well, as long as it starts with a number, you'd need:

```
egrep '^[0-9][0-9a-z]+[.][0-9][0-9]'
```

`[0-9a-z]` matches any number 0-9, and any letter a-z.

Comment: if single quotes are not intepreted in double quotes, would it be safe to

    bktitle="BASH"
    echo "New book title $bktitle added successfully!"

so when you say $ matches the end of the string? does it mean the last char of the string? or when you use it like this "^[0-9]+$" it means starting with 0-9 and must occur at least once and end with it?

Answer (score 1):

1. `"New book title '$bktitle' added successfully!"` is a double quoted string that happens to contain some single quotes.  If you want to see the literal text `'$bktitle'`, you could use: `"New book title '"'$bktitle'"' added successfully!"` which is 3 strings (two double quoted (one of which ends with a single quote and one of which starts with a single quote) and one single quoted) concatenated together.
2. `$` matches the end of line.
3. `1a.00` does not match because it is not of the form 'beginning of line followed by some number of digits followed by a literal `.`   But it would match `^[0-9]+[a][.][0-9][0-9]`, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.
1. But i thought the single quotes would display literal text? As in all the codes i posted is doing exactly what i want but i dont understand the logic behind them.
2. So since $ matches the line, "1a1" would be successful?
3. But doesnt it mean the preceding 0-9 should occur at least once followed by a . and two decimal place numbers. so why would 1a.00 not match?

Comment: Single quotes will display literal text.  But if you put single quotes inside a double quoted string then you still have a double quoted string and variables are interpolated.  No "1a1" contains a character other than [0-9], so it doesn't match.